# Does C++11 or C++14 support three or multiple valued logic?

Tags: c++, c++11, boolean-logic, c++14, tribool

I am wondering if C++11 or C++14 supports three or multiple valued logic. If not, any existing library does it?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple valued logic"?  You can switch on any integral type (but there's no equivalent to Fortran's arithmetic if).

Comment: You mean something like boost::tribool? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/tribool.html

Comment: A quick search does not show language support or any library that looks to support it; there are links related to VHDL (Hardware Description Language) but nothing concrete; me think you will have to implement it.

Comment: @mkaes Yes. The boost::tribool seems to meet my requirements.

Comment: Boost tribool is new to me, although it looks a bit like a simplified form o Fuzzy Logic. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic

Comment: `boost::tribool` has been there since [version 1.32](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/doc/html/tribool.html#tribool.introduction). So really no need for C++11/14 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost tribool provides an interface for three-state logic. It doesn't require c++11 or c++1y.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/tribool.html